# Filter Landsat 7 SLC-off scenes when running cubo.create

Tags: python, landsat

How to remove the Landsat 7 SLC-off scenes when running cubo.create (https://cubo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) ?
Here is my original code:

```
import cubo

da = cubo.create(
   lat=3.183376976287226,
   lon=31.25171910907124,
   collection="landsat-c2-l2",
   bands=['red', 'nir08'],
   start_date="2000-01-01",
   end_date="2005-12-31",
   edge_size=32,
   resolution=30,
   query={}
   )
```

I could remove the Landsat 7 scenes older than 31st of May 2003 from `da`, but I wonder if I could simply do it using the query.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to get data up until landsat 7's Scan Line Corrector (SLC) failed, which you could plug in as the `end_date` in the query (thus, problem solved)? Why can't you do that, or what is the issue? If not, could you clarify?

Comment: To answer @ori-yarden-phd, I could do it several tedious ways (getting all Landsat 5, then all Landsat 7 til 31st of May and combine them, or get all Landsat til 31st of May, and then only Landsat 5 and combine,...). What I would like to know is if it is possible to not load the Landsat 7 without SLC-off simply by adding in the query something like "slc-off = False". It would be much simpler.